# Type definition for a function that has a particular 'this' object

Tags: typescript

I want to create a series of objects that look like this:

```
type MyThing<T> = {
    data: T; 
    fn: ???;
}

const foo = {
    data: {
       foo: "bar"
    }, 
    fn: function() {
       return `Hello ${this.data.foo}!`; 
    }
}
```

In order for this to work, you must use the long form `function` syntax and not an arrow function.

How would I type this function such that it would cause an error if someone were to use an arrow function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You type the `this` arg with the special `this: SomeType` argument.

[Read more about the `this` parameter here in the docs.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters)

```
type MyThing<T> = {
    data: T; 
    fn: (this: MyThing<T>) => void;
}

const foo = {
    data: {
       foo: "bar"
    }, 
    fn: () => {
       return `Hello ${this.data.foo}!`; 
       // The containing arrow function captures the global value of 'this'.(7041)
       // Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof globalThis' has no index signature.(7017)
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAqALAlgOwOYB54D4oF4oBvAKCnKgBMBDYagLingG4oyKAzVRgCmBQDOjOEjRZcASgJ4AbgHtklZiQC+JEgGM5qAcCgc5cgsXbkadRqQrWDcxgCIARtQBO901BUAaNje5QeKXw8K2sKAHpwqAgAD0gNPWpUaJcXORcPChcIYABXF2SAAwAJCAAbMqMAEiJ+ZAEAOnNqBtsVAEJC1g81FSA)